# Case assignment rule when closing a case

Tags: case, assignment-rules

I have an auto assignment rule on Cases which assigns a case to a queue when closing a case.
I see that the rule is evaluated as false, meaning that after closing a case the system doesn't consider it as closed.
The check-box of use assignment rules is checked on the detail page.
I'm using the Close Case page not changing the status list.
Is that a bug or a feature?
What is the workaround?

Comment: Are you using the standard "Closed" status, or is it a new Status?  It is set as a 'closed status' option?  What about the assignment rule?  What does it evaluate to reassign?  More info please.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post your current formula but I would confirm that the actual status being set is set up at the field level as a "Closed" value.

You could use a workflow rule with a field update  to assign the ownership to the queue.

Comment: The formula is fine, I see it in the developer console. Can I change owner in field update action? I thought I couldn't

Comment: Yes, you can update the owner.

Comment: So this seems to be a bug in SF business flow...